Does original primary need to be patched as part of CU patching or does Microsoft support a delayed patch of the original primary node?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/upgrading-always-on-availability-group-replica-instances?view=sql-server-ver16
This document applies for cumulative updates as well.
The recommendation is to:

Patch the secondary N2
Failover to N2
Patch the original primary N1
Optionally failback to N1

My question is - can I have a one week gap between step 2 and step 3? The intention is to allow one week of operations post one node patching. And if all good then next week patch the other node.
Or is it recommended to do steps 1 to 4 as part of the patching process?
I have done the testing on dev environment and don't see any issue if I have a gap between steps 2 and 3. But I cannot find any Microsoft guidelines whether this is supported.
